# Instagram follower and following count mismatch

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram

When scraping the Instagram profile page of an account, it shows 3 numbers: posts, followers, and following. There is a request to Instagram's APIs that corresponds to these numbers.

If you look at the other request which loads the account's page itself (a document-type request), in the meta tags there's a meta tag that looks like this:

```html
<meta property="og:description" content="X Followers, Y Following, Z Posts - See Instagram photos and videos from account_name (username)" />
```

But these three numbers differ (I dare say always are greater) than the ones returned from the API. Which set of numbers is correct and why this mismatch occurs? Does it take some time for the API to process interactions and posting or something like that?

Comment: It’s possible that one (or both) of these data sources is cached somewhere in the stack to ease the load on their backend. However, it’s impossible to answer this question here - those who would *affirmatively* know the answers are likely under a nondisclosure agreement which would necessarily preclude them from revealing protected trade secrets about Instagram’s back end architecture. As such, I’m not quite sure what you would consider a full & complete answer to this question.

Comment: API is always correct.

Comment: @esqew the response from API in fields related to these numbers is prefixed with `edge_something`, e.g. `edge_follow_count`. The difference is kinda huge, in one case it showed around 70 more followers on meta tag, and 1 in post count, but that's weird because the UI shows data from API, hence should be fresher and I assume the meta is for search engines. Also you can check that if you post the UI updates almost instantly!

Comment: @jkalandarov I'll appreciate if you provided more evidence and information, unless you're working in Instagram!

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few reasons for why this might be happening. However, as you already mentioned, without an internal source, we can't be sure why *this specific case* is showing different metrics in 2 different places. Here are a few possible guesses:

### There are delays between the HTML metadata to the GraphQL API.

As documented in the [Instagram API for User Insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/insights#limitations):

> Data used to calculate metrics may be delayed up to 48 hours.

It's possible that while writing the metrics or building the HTML content itself, the backend injects the most updated data available via a database call. However, when the page dynamically calls this data using a GraphQL API request, the data returned is delayed.

This would explain the difference in data, however even a delay of 48 hours doesn't seem to justify some of the differences in numbers that you see between the 2 metrics.

### Different cluster regions in the TAO API

Under the hood, Instagram and Facebook use a complex yet efficient system called [TAO (The Associations and Objects)](https://engineering.fb.com/2013/06/25/core-data/tao-the-power-of-the-graph/). The linked article is a great read, but I will summarize the important parts:

> For every association type a so-called inverse type can be specified. Whenever an edge of the direct type is created or deleted between objects with unique IDs id1 and id2, TAO will **automatically create or delete an edge** of the corresponding inverse type in the opposite direction (id2 to id1). The intent is to help the application programmer maintain referential integrity for relationships that are naturally mutual, **like friendship**, or where support for graph traversal in both directions is performance critical, as for example in **“likes” and “liked by.”**

This means that likes and follow counts are great examples of where the TAO API  is applicable and used.

> The data set managed by TAO is **partitioned into hundreds of thousands of shards.** ... Shards can be migrated or cloned among servers in the same cluster to **equalize the load and to smooth out load spikes**. Load spikes are common and happen when a handful of objects or associations become extremely popular as they appear in the News Feeds of tens of millions of users at the same time.

The blog post helps wrap this up nicely with the following (shortened) excerpt:

> If a cache miss occurs on the follower, the follower attempts to fill its cache from a second tier, which talk directly to a MySQL cluster in that region. All TAO **writes** go through followers to leaders. Caches are updated as the reply to a successful write propagates back down the chain of clusters. Leaders are responsible for maintaining cache consistency within a region.

> For many of our products, TAO **losing consistency is a lesser evil** than losing availability. TAO tries hard to guarantee with high probability that **users always see their own updates**.

### To summarize...

The inconsistencies between the account metrics are probably due to a mix of delay of data, as shown in the 48 hour delay in the Instagram API docs, and because of low request rate, which in turn causes the Instagram TAO API to return old shard (database) data due to cache misses.

Comment: I'll definitely check those links, but are you telling me that suppose today I get posts, followers, and following as __a, b, and c__ from API, and __x, y, and z__ in the meta tag; Then if I check the API (or the official site) again in roughly 48 hours and get __m,n, and o__ should this be true: `x == m, y == n, z == o`?

Comment: I'm saying that a delay is one of the reasons for the differences, but the other reason is caching. The data is invalid on purpose so that the backend doesn't have to re-query it from the database every time.

Comment: Do you mean they won't converge to a certain number at all?

Comment: One other question: To sum it up, the actual and freshest data is the one in the _meta tag_ as you said it is populated directly by the database, and may in some time in the future (e.g. 48 hours or so) the **API** be updated to reflect those numbers? So I should refer to _meta tag_ for the most accurate numbers, is it right?

Comment: Yes, there is no guarantee they will ever become the same. Theoretically, if the page was visited often, then the results would be more accurate- "TAO tries hard to guarantee with high probability that users always see their own updates". To answer your final question, yes, the meta tag seems to hold the most accurate numbers.

Comment: But there's a catch: I observed a tiny page, (**less than 100 followers**). It **once reached 57 followers**, but **one person unfollowed** it. Now on the official site (and _API_), it shows **56 followers**, but in the meta tag, **it's 57**! How do you explain this? PS: Unless something weird happens, I'm gonna give you the bounty in a couple of days.

Comment: Again, as I said, neither metric is 100% accurate due to caching, but the meta tag seems to be me updated more frequently for large pages. My guess is that the TAO API realizes it's a large page, and hence caches the API more.